# c++ OpenGL undefined references

Tags: c++, opengl, ubuntu

I am trying to get OpenGL to work on my linux machine using c++ by following this [tutorial](http://www.videotutorialsrock.com/opengl_tutorial/get_opengl_setup_linux/text.php)

I am using Ubuntu 12.04 LTS. I have both packages  `freeglut3-dev` and `mesa-common-dev` which I installed by `sudo apt-get install package-name1 package-name2`

Just to be sure I went to the recommended directory `/usr/include/GL` and listed the files with `ls`:

```
freeglut_ext.h  freeglut.h  freeglut_std.h  glext.h  gl.h  gl_mangle.h  glu.h  glu_mangle.h  glut.h  glxext.h  glx.h  glx_mangle.h  internal
```

I noted that I do have `gl.h` and `glut.h` so I tested the sample program as recommended by the tutorial. I downloaded the zip file, unzipped the files into the same directory and then ran the `make` utility. Here is some output after running `make`

```
g++ -Wall -o cube main.cpp imageloader.cpp -lglut
imageloader.cpp: In function ‘Image* loadBMP(const char*)’:
imageloader.cpp:141:2: warning: suggest parentheses around ‘&&’ within ‘||’ [-Wparentheses]
/tmp/ccWT2wvp.o:main.cpp:function loadTexture(Image*): error: undefined reference to 'glGenTextures'
/tmp/ccWT2wvp.o:main.cpp:function loadTexture(Image*): error: undefined reference to 'glBindTexture'
/tmp/ccWT2wvp.o:main.cpp:function loadTexture(Image*): error: undefined reference to 'glTexImage2D'
```

I got about  20 other undefined reference errors. So, it must be that I do not have something installed correctly, or am missing files. I do note that I checked the hardware acceleration info by running `glxinfo` and I do have hardware acceleration.

1. How can I get OpenGL to work using c++

**EDIT** If I use a combination of both answers proved it works: Specifically I did the following:

```
someonespc:~/c++$ ls
imageloader.cpp  imageloader.h  main.cpp  Makefile  Makefile~  vtr.bmp
d2b2@d2b2-Aspire-7745G:~/c++$ g++ -Wall -lGL -o cube main.cpp imageloader.cpp -lglut -lGLU
imageloader.cpp: In function ‘Image* loadBMP(const char*)’:
imageloader.cpp:141:2: warning: suggest parentheses around ‘&&’ within ‘||’ [-Wparentheses]
someonespc:~/c++$ ls
cube  imageloader.cpp  imageloader.h  main.cpp  Makefile  Makefile~  vtr.bmp
```

Then I ran `./cube` and it worked! Please explain why putting `-lGL` and `-lGLU` worked

Comment: These warnings are from the linker, not the compiler.  You need to link to the library which provides OpenGL, possibly using `-lGL`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add `-lGL` to the gcc command line options. It tells the linker that the functions might be found in `libGL.so` (which is a link to `libGL.so.1`).

Answer (score 2):

I had this same error on Ubuntu 14.04 using Cmake

The answer for me was adding:
FIND_PACKAGE(OpenGL) at the beginning of my CMakeList.txt

and adding:
${OPENGL_gl_LIBRARY} to the end of the list in target_link_libraries()

Answer (score 1):

I used to write some OpenGL code on my Ubuntu, when checking the makefiles, I have everywhere two libraries linked. (glut and GLU)

Note that capitalization is important on linux-systems, since it will look for the file libGLU.so

Just tested with the code on the website and following command gives me an executable file:

```
g++ -Wall -o cube main.cpp imageloader.cpp -lglut -lGLU
```