# undefined reference to symbol glTexImage2D

Tags: c++, linux, opengl

I am trying to get OpenGL to work and have exactly the same problem like here:
[c++ OpenGL undefined references](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18034152/c-opengl-undefined-references)

I have both packages downloaded and used the same tutorial. Except I use Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS and my problem is not solved with the mentioned Solution.

It reduces the problem to one undefined reference but still does not work:

```
g++ -Wall -lGL -o cube main.cpp imageloader.cpp -lglut -lGLU 
...
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccWzhHjf.o: undefined reference to symbol 'glTexImage2D'
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/mesa/libGL.so.1: error adding symbols: DSO missing from
command line collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status make: *** [cube] Error 1
```

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: Please show your linker invocation. If you invoked through the compiler driver, its the one with the `-o` option.

Comment: I used: g++ -Wall -lGL -o cube main.cpp imageloader.cpp -lglut -lGLU

Comment: If `libGL` provides `glTexImage2D`, then you need to move `-lGL` to the end of the command. Order and placement of libraries matters (like `-lGL` and `-lGLU`). See the [`ld(1)` man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/ld).

Comment: Fixed! very nice. Thank you a lot.

Comment: You should add your solution as an Answer in an answer block. Then, accept your own answer so others know.

Answer (score 1):

Edit the Make File and change it to this

```
  CC = g++
CFLAGS = -Wall -lGL
PROG = cube

SRCS = main.cpp imageloader.cpp

ifeq ($(shell uname),Darwin)
    LIBS = -framework OpenGL -framework GLUT
else
    LIBS = -lglut -lGLU
endif

all: $(PROG)

$(PROG):    $(SRCS)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $(PROG) $(SRCS) $(LIBS)

clean:
    rm -f $(PROG)
```

What I did was I added -lGL to CFLAGS and -lGLU to LIBS to the flags so it could link with the required library

Answer (score 1):

```
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccWzhHjf.o: undefined reference to symbol 'glTexImage2D'
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/mesa/libGL.so.1: error adding symbols: DSO missing
```

The part `libGL.so.1` basically tells you that there is something wrong with the shared library (it is missing). So all you need to do is to add the GL library like this: `-lGL`. The reason it is not working even when you already have `-lGL` is that you need to move the library flags after the `.cpp` files. So this should work:

```
 g++ -Wall -o cube main.cpp imageloader.cpp -lGL -lglut -lGLU
```

If you have similiar errors just try to add the flag.